# Android save backstack fragment history

Tags: java, android

I put in backstack fragments: A->B->C->D, where A is starting fragment for activity. After pressed home button, use other apps and return in my app, activity restarted and i see fragment A. How can i save all history of backstack?

code example for addbackstack:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left,R.animator.slide_out_right,0,0)
            .replace(R.id.container, new SettingsContentFragment(item))
            .commit();
```

if it can help - i use NavigationDrawerFragment, part of my onCreate in activity:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        saveToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (saveToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(saveToolbar);
        }
        saveToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_ab_drawer);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);



        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)


getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.customSetArguments(items);
    mTitle = getTitle();
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
        R.id.navigation_drawer,
        (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
```

Comment: Basically you have to call `addToBackStack(String)`  method, but I think that you have more issues

Comment: why don't you save those details manually in onDestroy()?

Comment: did you check at which stage of your lifecycle does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You call `addToBackStack(null)` method before you perform a transaction. As a result nothing is actually added to back stack. Try

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
 .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left,R.animator.slide_out_right,0,0)
  .replace(R.id.container, new SettingsContentFragment(item))
  .addToBackStack(null)
  .commit();
```

instead

Comment: backstack is not empty, i can use it while app doesnot restart. I think, i should save information of fragments in savedinstancestate, but i dont know, how can i do that

Comment: Do you mean that you still can navigate D->C->B->A? I have an app with several fragments in similar scenario and,  use backstack and do not have described issue. Why are you mixing FragmentManager with SupportFtaentManager by the way?

Comment: @Nikitossss, did you solve the problem? I am looking into my code now, and I think see your possible problem.

Comment: In your `onCreate()` method in the activity (or in the other place you initially create fragments) check that stack is not empty. Otherwise, after activity restarts and recreates your fragments you add yet another one on top. That's how I did it in my `onCreate`: `// If activity was restarted no need to recreate the fragments
  if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
   // transaction to add fragment A
  }`. If this works I'll convert it to a new answer

Comment: @Kirill_K, can you write example?

Comment: @Nikitossss, ok, I'll do. In the meanwhile, can you check what happens after you execute your scenario as described in the question and after unexpectedly seeing Fragment A press 'aback' button. What fragment you see, or what happens? Can you post the whole `onCreate()`, or a method there you initially add fragments to backstack please?

Comment: did you have any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052712/nested-fragment-backpress-child-inside-parent-have-problem

Answer (score 0):

Android already does that. The trick is that you mustn't overwrite it yourself.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) { // <-- add this
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left,R.animator.slide_out_right,0,0)
                .replace(R.id.container, new SettingsContentFragment(item))
                .commit();
    }
```