# Nested Fragment Back Press Child Inside Parent is Causing a Problem

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I have nested fragment, fragment inside fragment. Using **NavigationBottomView**. Everything goes right when I backpress from parent to child fragment.

But now, if I am inside child fragment and suddenly my phone screen goes off, and if I Open the screen again and backpress from where I left, it's not going I think it is forgot or clear my backstack. Don't know why. I have made a demo on github link below

```
MessageListningFragment messageListningFragment = new MessageListningFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.addToBackStack( null );
    transaction.replace( R.id.dynamic_container, messageListningFragment ).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

[github demo link is here](https://github.com/sunil-singh-chaudhary/Fragment-Nested-Child-Backpress/tree/master)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should either use a ViewPager/ViewPager2 with NavHost fragments or implement BottomNavigationView with [extension functions](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) Google provided, which basically tags fragments and add them with `NavHostFragment.create()`.

`NavHostFragment` takes care of childFragmentManager and back stack management. You can check out examples [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/NavigationComponents-Tutorials) if you wish.